# iOS: sizeWithFont: for custom font

Tags: ios, uilabel, sizewithfont

I've been plugging away and I need to use the sizeWithFont: method to properly line up my layout, but it doesn't seem to work with custom fonts. Is there a way to get it to work, or maybe another method I can use?

I'm pretty stumped on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the custom font is loading properly, and that you're getting the size for the variant of the font (regular, bold, etc.) that you are actually using?

Comment: Yes. It is definitely working. If I set the size manually, the proper font shows up on the view. I have added the ttf files to the project and implemented them in my plist file under the key 'UIAppFonts'.

Comment: Hm, it should definitely be working.  Is it not returning anything at all, or just incorrect values?

Comment: Actually, after further inspection, it may not be working. The font information is all null/0.0f. What could be the problem. When I try viewing the ttf in XCode, it shows all of the letters as per usual and I have put the fonts into the plist. It seems that everything SHOULD work. Given that the font isn't actually being pulled, can I do something now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sizeWithFont should definitely work, but if it's giving you a problem then there is a workaround.  You can put the text in a UITextView, add it to your layout, and then retrieve the actual text size and adjust accordingly.  Here's some sample code from one of my projects:

```
     // Put in the title in
    self.titleView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 195, 195)];
    self.titleView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bliss Pro" size:20.0];
    [self addSubview:self.titleView];

    self.titleView.text = @"Add your text here";

    // Now get the actual size of the text and resize the title view's frame
    CGRect frame = self.titleView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.titleView.contentSize.height;
    self.titleView.frame = frame;
```

It's a bit hackish, but it certainly works.

Comment: Right! I've had to use this method before to incorporate a description with highlight for copy and paste. But I've figured out the answer and it probably should be known as well. If you come around, could you add it to your answer so that it will have both answers in it?

Comment: The answer is that font names aren't necessarily the same as the name of the file. I was using Gotham-Bold.ttf and I ended up having to import "Gotham Bold", instead of "Gotham-Bold". I wasn't the one to get the font, just to implement it, so its good to know.

Comment: My bad Leena, I forgot to add the line where you actually set the text for the UITextView.  Once there is actual text in the view to calculate the height of, the code will work.  I added the line in now.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define kFontSize 14.0    //modify your font size
CGSize size = [yourView sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize]];
```